# Select último registro de JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Tenho uma tabela `tb_processos` e outra `tb_detalhes` (guarda detalhes de um determinado processo), gostaria de pegar todos os dados do processo e somente o último detalhe do processo.

Da forma como estou fazendo busco todos os registros de `tb_detalhes` relacionado a determinado processo:

```
SELECT 
    tb_processo.nm_empresa,
    tb_processo.dt_solicitacao,
    tb_detalhes.desc_detalhes
FROM
    tb_processo 
    LEFT JOIN tb_detalhes ON tb_detalhes.id_processo = tb_processo.id_processo
```

Entretanto gostaria de pegar somente o último registro de `tb_detalhes`, ou seja vou exibir todos os dados do processo e o `desc_detalhes` do último registro inserido, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: use select limit 1.

Comment: @Marconi como limito somente dentro do JOIN? Porque na tabela tb_processo vou mostrar vários processos.

Comment: entendi, porque não faz uma function que retorna esse dado em vez de fazer um inner join?

Comment: poderia saber o que você representa por `nm`, em seu padrão?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert representa nome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você necessita é uma `SubQuery` não um `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    tb_processo.nm_empresa,
    tb_processo.dt_solicitacao,
    (
        SELECT  tb_detalhes.desc_detalhes
        FROM    tb_detalhes
        WHERE   tb_detalhes.id_processo = tb_processo.id_processo 
        ORDER BY tb_detalhes.id_detalhes DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS ultimo_detalhe
FROM
    tb_processo
```

Desta forma você esta buscando dentro da `query` `tb_processo`, um unico registro da tabela detalhes que pertença ao processo atual e seja o ultimo (`ORDER BY id_detalhes DESC`)

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigada.

Comment: Ou poderia ser uma  function como disse no comentario acima.

Comment: Estou precisando fazer o mesmo, como seria essa query no Codeigniter?